# Bcc Field in SMTP [ showing/not showing ] problem

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, bcc

I'm trying to use python's smtplib to send, via *gmail*, an email with bcc addresses.
I use this code:

```
#imports etc...
fromAddr = sender@origin.com
to = [ recpt1@destinationTo.com ]
cc = [ recpt2@destinationCc.com ]
bcc = [ recpt3@destinationBcc.com, recpt4@destinationBcc.com ]
server = SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587)
#starttls, login, etc..
content = "Hello, this is a message."
msg = "From: %s\r\nTo:%s\r\nCc: %s\r\n\r\n%s" % ( from, to, cc, content )
server.sendmail( fromAddr, to + cc + bcc, msg )
#server.quit() etc...
```

-> When I go to the respective Inboxs I get the same message for all the addresses in [to+cc+bcc], wich is right. But

what i would like to happen was that each bcc address got a bcc field with its own address in it, just like is described in [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=57143) for the web interface of *gmail*.

This is what I wish to accomplish:

Cc and To Inboxes:

```
To: recpt1@destinationTo.com
From: sender@origin.com
Cc: recpt2@destinationCc.com
(...)
```

recpt3 Inbox:

```
To: recpt1@destinationTo.com
From: sender@origin.com
Cc: recpt2@destinationCc.com
Bcc: recpt3@destinationBcc.com
(...)
```

recpt4 Inbox:

```
To: recpt1@destinationTo.com
From: sender@origin.com
Cc: recpt2@destinationCc.com
Bcc: recpt4@destinationBcc.com
(...)
```

Has anyone managed to get this working? I've been looking in the smtp rfc documents and I've found nothing, I dont understand how gmail can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that gmail does a separate SMTP session for each BCC recipient.  If everything between your two comments were a function `dosend(fromAddr, toAddr, content, to, cc, bcc=None)` you might do something like this:

```
dosend(fromAddr, to+cc, content, to, cc)
for t in bcc:
    dosend(fromAddr, t, content, to, cc, t)
```

That would send it once to the `to` and `cc` address(es), then send it again to each `bcc` address individually, with the appropriate bcc header.  Just to clarify what dosend does: the `fromAddr` and `toAddr` arguments are for the envelope (the first and second arguments to `server.sendmail`).  The `to`, `cc`, and (optional) `bcc` arguments are for the headers in `msg`.  (Your code doesn't add a Bcc, you would need to add that if the optional argument `bcc` is provided.)

(Edit: I deleted my comments about the possibility it might use X-Bcc.  I just tried it, and it works as described above.  I also fixed up and clarified the description of `dosend`.)

Comment: I've found something in the [smtp's rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). It seems that "*SMTP systems that are aware of "bcc"* " are suposed to use the method you've described. ( paragraph 7.2 @ the rfc2822 )